# mkdir fails to create directory

Tags: php, mkdir

I've been through most similar posts and all over the web trying this and the other to no avail. Recently put a site on ehosts.com and ever since enjoy all sorts of freak stuff.

Identical scripts work fine on a number of sites and hosts so maybe this is a hosting issue and should probably go some other place? The scenario is that mkdir randomly works before refusing further service again for no obvious reason.

I am aware this is not much of a programming issue and likely off-topic for SO, but perhaps someone could still point me in the right direction before the question is closed.

The code is as simple as `mkdir($dir, 0777)` In addition I have played with 
`$mask = umask(0)` before and `umask($mask)` after the mkdir call. Plus, I checked permissions and `is_writable($dir)` and all is well. I'm out of ideas, hence the post.

EDIT: Here is the funny part:

```
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
  $mask = umask(0);
  mkdir($dir);
  umask($mask);
}
```

Nothing in error log.

Comment: Checked you logs?

Comment: Hardly anything we can say, is there? We don't know your system, we don't know the file system layout, nothing. And we are quite convinced that the `mkdir()` function works as documented. So what do you expect from us?

Comment: @arkasha: I assumed 'a number of sites and hosts' would have sufficiently catered that part of your question. The mkdir function works OK if I export that part of the script and run it by itself. I have debugged the rest of it and it's perfectly valid. Hence my posting here.

Comment: show us code and errorlog